# Youtube iframe player API 'onReady' event does not get triggered inspite of suggested fixes

Tags: youtube-api

I'm using the youtube iframe player API for an app that I'm building. Everything worked fine until about a month ago (Feb 2014). None of the events get fired now, not even 'OnReady'. One of the posts suggested adding "origin=" to the src attribute. That didn't fix it for me. Here's a snippet of my code - I'm using angularjs.

HTML:

```
<iframe id="player" width="1280" height="720" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-PXgGnKhEdQ?autoplay=1&theme=light&color=white&origin=http://127.0.0.1:8000">
```

Javascript:

```
$scope.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function(id) {
    var player = new YT.Player('player', {
        videoId: id,
        events: {
            'onReady': function (event) {
                 player.addEventListener('onStateChange', function(e) {
                     console.log('onReady');
                 });
             },
             'onStateChange': function (event) {
                 console.log('onStateChange')
             }
        }
    });
}
```

The video plays and stops, but these events do not get fired. I also see an error "Error: Ad adLoadError error: Unable to request ads from server. Cause: Error #2032 errorCode: 1103". Not sure if that is interfering with the event mechanism.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Deepa

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML got wiped out, Deepa, but I can tell what you're trying to do.

I'd written out an iframe, they called new YT.Player on that iframe id and it was working fine until a few weeks ago.  After some research, I saw that every few months YouTube breaks that functionality -- but they never break the functionality where you use the new YT.Player to write out the iframe for you.  The latest ticket RE this I saw in the google api bugs is

https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6218

I stopped banging my head against it and rebuilt my implementation using their default method, even though the documentation says that the approach where you attach YT.Player to an already-written iframe is fine.

Comment: Ditto - I just re-implemented to let YT.Player write the iframe, and that fixed the lack of onReady in IE9.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `rel=0` in the iframe src

Your HTML need to be changed like this

```
<iframe id="player" width="1280" height="720" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-PXgGnKhEdQ?rel=0&autoplay=1&theme=light&color=white&origin=http://127.0.0.1:8000">
```

I hope you have included the script in your page

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```